# How to remove Postfix queue messages sent to a specific domain

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I have a server with multiple domains. How can I clear all Postfix queue messages for a specific domain?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

UPDATE 2021-04-18:

```
mailq | tail -n +2 | grep -v '^ *(' | awk  'BEGIN { RS = "" } { if ($8 ~ /@example\.com/ && $9 == "") print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | postsuper -d -
```

Whereas `$7`=sender, `$8`=recipient1, `$9`=recipient2. You can also adapt the rule for other recipients (`$9`) to your needs.

The command is based on an example of the [postsuper manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/postsuper.1.html) which an example command matching a full recipient mail address:

```
mailq | tail -n +2 | grep -v '^ *(' | awk  'BEGIN { RS = "" } { if ($8 == "user@example.com" && $9 == "") print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | postsuper -d -
```

---

Old content:

This command deletes all mails sent from or to addresses that end with `@example.com`:

```
sudo mailq | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } /@example\.com$/ { print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | sudo postsuper -d -
```

Comment: On Linux, use `tail -n +2` instead of `tail +2`.

Comment: The `tr -d` can be refactored into the Awk script, too. Replace `{ print $1 }` with `{ r = $1; gsub(/[!*]/, "", r); print r }`

Comment: If you copy, edit and paste the example from postsuper `man` page, you'll avoid unwanted side effects.

Comment: @symcbean Thanks for the hint, I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 11):

**Grep solution**

`mailq | grep example.com -B1 | grep -oE "^[A-Z0-9]{10,11}" | sudo postsuper -d -`

assumes ID is between 10 and 11 digits, (based on inodes)

Answer (score 8):

I have tried this solution in ubuntu 12.04, and it doesn't work this way:

```
sudo mailq | tail +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / @example\.com$/ { print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | sudo postsuper -d -
```

I need to change to this way:

```
postqueue -p | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } /@example\.com/ { print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | postsuper -d -
```

Comment: yes, you have to eliminate the space before the "@".

Answer (score 2):

Look at [pfdel.pl](http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/postfix-queue-delete-en/), a mandatory tool to manage the queue. It takes a regexp and remove the mails waiting in queue corresponding to your domain.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give a "more modern" answer parsing the `json` output of `postqueue -j`. It depends on the package `jq` to filter the output and is much more understandable (and debuggable):

```
postqueue -j | jq -rc 'select(.recipients[].address | match(".*@example\\.com$"))["queue_id"]' | postsuper -d -

# For an exact Mail match
postqueue -j | jq -rc 'select(.recipients[].address == "address@example.com")["queue_id"]' | postsuper -d -
```

Another less related argument for this solution besides readability is it's easy adaptability:

```
# Filter on delay_reason being "Connection timed out"
postqueue -j | jq -rc 'select(.recipients[].delay_reason | match(".*Connection timed out$"))["queue_id"]' | postsuper -d -

# Filter on arrival_time being older than certain age
postqueue -j | jq -rc 'select(.arriveal_time < 1710265065)["queue_id"]' | postsuper -d -

# Filter on the size of messages
postqueue -j | jq -rc 'select(.message_size > 100000)["queue_id"]' | postsuper -d -
```

This is the full json, showing all filterable values:

```
{
  "queue_name": "deferred",
  "queue_id": "4TwLyJ4Gpyz2xVB",
  "arrival_time": 1710407000,
  "message_size": 15932,
  "forced_expire": false,
  "sender": "MAILER-DAEMON",
  "recipients": [
    {
      "address": "no-reply@example.com",
      "delay_reason": "delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mail.example.com[111.222.333.444]:25: Connection timed out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to delete messages from or to e-mail addresses at a specific domain, this command works for me:

```
mailq | \
  tail -n +2 | \
  awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / @example\.com$/ { print $1 }' | \
  tr -d '*!' | \
  postsuper -d -
```

Also works for deleting e-mails from or to specific e-mail *addresses* by supplying for example `mail@example\.com$/` instead of `@example\.com$/`.

Taken from [a comment on howtoforge.com](http://www.howtoforge.com/delete-mails-to-or-from-a-specific-email-address-from-postfix-mail-queue#comment-33638). See there for related solutions and the command in one line. (I used bash line continuation for readability).

A very similar command that allows to make deletion dependent on whether the address appears as sender, recipient etc. is found in `man postsuper`, where it says about `-d`:

> For example, to delete all mail with exactly one recipient user@example.com:
>
> ```
> mailq | \
>   tail -n +2 | \
>   grep -v '^ *(' | \
>   awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } { if ($8 == "user@example.com" && $9 == "") print $1 }' | \
>   tr -d '*!' | \
>   postsuper -d -
> ```

(The variables mean: $7=sender, $8=recipient1, $9=recipient2. I changed the quote to use `tail -n +2`, since their `tail +2` does not work any more, at least on some modern systems.)

Comment: The space before `@example\.com` seems wrong.

Comment: The backslashes at the end of line are not actually necessary; the shell understands that the command continues on the next line if the last token is `|` (or `||` or `&&` or a bunch of others).

Answer (score -3):

I've modified it little bit:

mailq | grep  -B1 | grep -oE "^[A-Z0-9]{12}" | xargs -I% postsuper -d %

Comment: Then please explain why and what this is supposed to do.

Comment: Running hundreds of instances of `postsuper` is not an improvement at all. `xargs` is nice when you use it properly, but this is not one of those situations.